# php print result from two table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

i fetch two table result in one query. now i have in each table one row with `name = userid`. when i print id of table one, this not worked and printed id of table two . in i.e i select `*` from product and then `voteid,userid` form voteproduct where userid = $userid ; now i need print userid from product table but my result print userid from voteproduct . how to fix this ? thanks

my code :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . PREFIX  . '_product,' . PREFIX  . '_voteproduct WHERE ' . PREFIX  . '_voteproduct.voteid = ' . PREFIX  . '_product.id AND ' . PREFIX  . '_voteproduct.userid =  "' . $userid . '" ORDER BY name ' . $pages->limit .' ';

    $db->query($sql) or error ('ERROR', mysql_error ());
          $result = $db->query ( $sql ); 
          if($db->numrows($result)>0){ 
          while ($row = $db->fetcharray($result))
       {

    echo $row['userid']; // PROBELM THIS PRINTED USERID FROM VOTEPRODUCT I NEED PRINT USER ID FROM PRODUCT
       }
```

**EDIT** : If I selected `*` from my product table, realy i need to all. ( name, price, date, category, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select each userid with `AS`  in order to use them separately like below

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.userid as pid, vp.userid as vpid, ... FROM ' . PREFIX  . '_product AS p,' . PREFIX  . '_voteproduct AS vp WHERE vp.voteid = p.id AND vp.userid =  "' . $userid . '" ORDER BY name ' . $pages->limit .' ';
```

And use ;

```
echo $row['pid'];
```

Comment: i see this error : Unknown column 'p.userid' in 'field list. u read my edited question?

Comment: i forgot to alias table names, i updated the sql, you can try now

Comment: New error : Unknown column 'portals_voteproduct.voteid' in 'where clause'

Comment: Also updated the aliases of condition side, try again with new code updated

Comment: +1, This Worked. I need to print Price, Category,date and more result form product. now i add each row with p.price as pprice,p.category as pcategory, p.date as pdate, .... ?!

Answer (score 3):

`select *` is a lazy way of doing thigns, especially when it looks like you're only asking for a SINGLE field. You don't run to the store, grab the entire store's shelf stock, take it home, then throw away EVERYTHING except the one candy bar you wanted.

How about

```
SELECT product.userid
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

so you get only the exact single field you need?

Comment: @Marc B : you analogy is right +1 when i need to one row form product table, BUT i need to all row of the product table (name,date,price, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.userid as puserid, v.userid as vuserid ... FROM ' . PREFIX  . '_product p,' . PREFIX  . '_voteproduct v where ...

echo $row['puserid'];
```